# Изучение ООП в php

Tags: ооп, php

Доброго времени суток. Начал изучать php и вот дошла чреда к ООП. Кто может посоветовать хорошую литературу или видеоуроки это не важно. Да, религия мне не запрещает искать в поисковике, просто хотелось бы узнать мнение экспертов которые могут посоветовать, что-то толковое, а вот д*рьма в инете тоже хватает, надеюсь на вашу помощь :)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php

Comment: Благодарю.

Comment: Но вообще, как по мне, то лучше всего ООП учить либо в Java, либо в С++ - оно там как бы ООПешнее)

Comment: :) Еще придет и их черед ^^ ахах))

Comment: Как учить ООП С++ имея знания синтаксиса PHP SilverIce ?Вот Java еще понять через раз можно...

Comment: Учить ООП сразу на С++ - это лучше сразу застрелиться (шучу). С++ - язык не для обучения основ чего-то, а для других целей (развития интеллекта. или просто для развития усидчивости и терпения). Лучше джава или питон.

Comment: http://bankknig.net/knigi/228442-php-obekty-shablony-i-metodiki-izd-3-e.html вот сейчас читаю, хорошая книга (не знаю, доступны ли закачки)

Comment: @SilverIce, Java, это по-моему сплошное ООП. Постоянная работа с классами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.su/lessons/?lesson_0

тут сразу уроки, справочник, ссылки на денверы, подробно все рассказывают )

ну и конкретно по ООП: http://www.php.su/learnphp/phpoo/

Answer (score 1):

скачай книгу "PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования"

Comment: я уже писал в комментариях